# Android - Google Spreadsheet Api

Tags: java, android, api, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I can't get which libs i should use for developing an Android app that menages Google spreadsheet. I need connecting, copying, editing, reading from a user spreadsheet but i can't understand today which is the way.

```
Google Drive Api : https://developers.google.com/drive/
Google Spreadsheet Api: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/
Google APi java client: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/
```

Which is the correct one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the end the libraries i used are:

```
gdata-client-1.0.jar
gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar
gdata-core-1.0.jar
gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar
gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar
google-api-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-api-client-android-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-android-1.12.0-beta.jar
google-oauth-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
gson-2.1.jar
guava-13.0.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar
```

As suggested by Eugenio (thanks for that!!!) i "mixed" libraries from spreadsheet api with the java-client-api and after the authentication i used the following for getting the cells

```
SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = null;
URL metafeedUrl = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

SpreadsheetFeed spreadsheetFeed = service.getFeed(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = spreadsheetFeed.getEntries();
for (SpreadsheetEntry entry : spreadsheets) {
   if (entry.getTitle().getPlainText().equals(spreadsheetTitle)) {
      spreadsheet = entry;
   }
}

if (spreadsheet == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find the required spreadsheet '" + spreadsheetTitle + "'");
}

WorksheetEntry worksheet = null;
WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
    for (WorksheetEntry entry : worksheets) {
    if (entry.getTitle().getPlainText().equals(worksheetTitle)) {
         worksheet = entry;
    }
}

if (worksheet == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find the required worksheet '" + worksheetTitle + "'");
}

URL listFeedUrl = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
ListFeed listFeed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);
```

For the moment i used the "worst" authentication system and i should turn this in the OAuth2 but for the moment the ClientLogin is done in this way:

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("v1");
service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);
service.setUserCredentials(email, password);
```

Comment: i actually never worked on it again.. i used ontly the described authentication. Sorry..

Comment: but it will return all the spreadsheets, how cloud i try to access specific spread sheet

Comment: @Fasiha it actually selects one specific speadsheet...and one specific worksheet inside it too... give a try to the code...

Answer (score 23):

Short answer: All three

Long answer:

You will have to use the new [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/), which allows to upload, download and modify files in Google Drive. With this you only have limited operations on spreadsheets, basically download it or upload it.

The [Google Spreadsheet Api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) allows to make complex operations in spreadsheets, like accessing data by row and column.

The [Google API java client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) is a dependency in all Google APIs, it is used to authorize the connection in different ways, such as OAuth or service accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! ..do you have any tutorial or a downloadable example? i cannot understand how to integrate them together..

Comment: Well, not with all three together, but [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API) uses client API and Drive API, using Spreadsheet API should be straightforward after that

Comment: @EugenioCuevas The link is dead.

Comment: is there an example of doing the OAuth 2.0 in android? it has do be done before accessing the sheets API right?