# saving app data on google-spreadsheet

Tags: java, android, google-sheets

I am using the following code taken from

```
public static void StoreDataonGoogleSheet (String DonName, String Donphnum, String Donemail ) {
    final MediaType FORM_DATA_TYPE
            = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    //URL derived from form URL
    final String URL="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScLsfd71Y_p__QK1YUCYXGWrPmrbENQ8-HhBVlt9w7UoX2HJg/formResponse";
    //https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScLsfd71Y_p__QK1YUCYXGWrPmrbENQ8-HhBVlt9w7UoX2HJg/viewform
    //input element ids found from the live form page
    String postBody = "";
    final String NAME_KEY="entry.973164943";
    final String PHONE_KEY="entry.262426619";
    final String EMAIL_KEY="entry.125658837";
    try {
        postBody = NAME_KEY+"=" + URLEncoder.encode(DonName,"UTF-8") +
                "&" + PHONE_KEY + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Donphnum,"UTF-8") +
                "&" + EMAIL_KEY + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Donemail,"UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        //Create OkHttpClient for sending request
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        //Create the request body with the help of Media Type
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(FORM_DATA_TYPE, postBody);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        //Send the request
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    }catch (IOException exception){
    //    result=false;
    }
    //return result;

}
```

I have taken the code from

http://codesmith.in/post-data-google-drive-sheet-through-mobile-app/

The build of apk does not give any errors. But on execution, it says "app stopped working".

Can you throw some light on where I am going wrong?

adding the trace by attaching the device to the console

```
 10-23 10:50:59.675 31647-31647/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
 10-23 10:50:59.775 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out:      Sending WAIT chunk
 10-23 10:50:59.775 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/ActivityThread: Application ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
 10-23 10:51:00.155 31647-31653/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
 10-23 10:51:00.175 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: Debugger has connected
 10-23 10:51:00.175 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 10-23 10:51:00.375 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 10-23 10:51:00.575 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 10-23 10:51:00.786 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 10-23 10:51:00.986 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 10-23 10:51:01.186 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 10-23 10:51:01.386 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 10-23 10:51:01.586 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 10-23 10:51:01.787 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
 10-23 10:51:01.987 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: debugger has settled (1390)
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 22111: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 22113: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 22117: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 667: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 689: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
 10-23 10:51:02.037 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
 10-23 10:51:02.197 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
 10-23 10:51:02.197 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 457: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
 10-23 10:51:02.197 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
 10-23 10:51:02.237 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
 10-23 10:51:02.237 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 630: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
 10-23 10:51:02.237 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
 10-23 10:51:02.237 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
 10-23 10:51:02.237 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 632: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
 10-23 10:51:02.237 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
 10-23 10:51:02.407 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.Spinner.getPopupContext, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.getPopupContext
 10-23 10:51:02.407 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22901: Landroid/widget/Spinner;.getPopupContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
 10-23 10:51:02.407 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000d
 10-23 10:51:02.427 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/ListPopupWindow: Could not find method setEpicenterBounds(Rect) on PopupWindow. Oh well.
 10-23 10:51:02.507 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
 10-23 10:51:02.507 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 194 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
 10-23 10:51:02.507 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
 10-23 10:51:02.617 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.<init>
 10-23 10:51:02.617 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 2707 (Landroid/widget/ThemedSpinnerAdapter;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter;
 10-23 10:51:02.617 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x0016
 10-23 10:51:02.627 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zzo.zzy
 10-23 10:51:02.627 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 587: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
 10-23 10:51:02.627 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
 10-23 10:51:02.948 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/GC: <tid=31647> OES20 ===> GC Version   : GC Ver rls_pxa988_KK44_GC13.25 
 10-23 10:51:02.978 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
 10-23 10:51:25.970 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: method Landroid/support/v7/widget/ListViewCompat;.lookForSelectablePosition incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/ListView;
 10-23 10:51:25.980 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.setPressedItem
 10-23 10:51:25.980 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18376: Landroid/support/v7/widget/DropDownListView;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
 10-23 10:51:25.980 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000a
 10-23 10:51:25.980 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.View.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.setPressedItem
 10-23 10:51:25.980 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 21696: Landroid/view/View;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
 10-23 10:51:25.980 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x004a
 10-23 10:51:26.020 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
 10-23 10:51:27.632 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/AbsListView: onDetachedFromWindow
 10-23 10:51:27.842 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
 10-23 10:51:40.855 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
 10-23 10:51:40.855 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a6ac08)
 10-23 10:51:40.865 31647-31647/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100, PID: 31647
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
                                                                                 at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
                                                                                 at ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100.RecordDonation.StoreDataonGoogleSheet(RecordDonation.java:306)
                                                                                 at ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100.RecordDonation.sendData(RecordDonation.java:388)
                                                                                 at ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100.RecordDonation$2.onClick(RecordDonation.java:217)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)



10-23 11:51:01.979 7755-7755/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-23 11:51:02.089 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
10-23 11:51:02.089 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/ActivityThread: Application ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
10-23 11:51:02.219 7755-7761/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
10-23 11:51:02.289 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: Debugger has connected
10-23 11:51:02.289 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-23 11:51:02.490 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-23 11:51:02.690 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-23 11:51:02.890 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-23 11:51:03.100 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-23 11:51:03.300 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-23 11:51:03.501 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-23 11:51:03.691 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-23 11:51:03.891 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/System.out: debugger has settled (1464)
10-23 11:51:03.941 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
10-23 11:51:03.941 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 22117: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
10-23 11:51:03.941 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 22119: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 22123: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 673: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 695: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
10-23 11:51:03.951 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
10-23 11:51:04.091 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
10-23 11:51:04.091 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 463: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
10-23 11:51:04.091 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
10-23 11:51:04.131 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
10-23 11:51:04.131 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 636: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
10-23 11:51:04.131 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-23 11:51:04.131 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
10-23 11:51:04.131 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 638: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
10-23 11:51:04.131 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-23 11:51:04.301 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.Spinner.getPopupContext, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.getPopupContext
10-23 11:51:04.301 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22907: Landroid/widget/Spinner;.getPopupContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
10-23 11:51:04.301 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000d
10-23 11:51:04.311 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/ListPopupWindow: Could not find method setEpicenterBounds(Rect) on PopupWindow. Oh well.
10-23 11:51:04.391 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
10-23 11:51:04.391 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 195 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
10-23 11:51:04.391 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
10-23 11:51:04.501 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.<init>
10-23 11:51:04.501 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 2708 (Landroid/widget/ThemedSpinnerAdapter;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter;
10-23 11:51:04.501 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x0016
10-23 11:51:04.511 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zzo.zzy
10-23 11:51:04.511 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 593: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
10-23 11:51:04.511 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
10-23 11:51:04.822 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/GC: <tid=7755> OES20 ===> GC Version   : GC Ver rls_pxa988_KK44_GC13.25 
10-23 11:51:04.852 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-23 11:51:08.816 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
10-23 11:51:33.610 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: method Landroid/support/v7/widget/ListViewCompat;.lookForSelectablePosition incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/ListView;
10-23 11:51:33.610 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.setPressedItem
10-23 11:51:33.610 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18382: Landroid/support/v7/widget/DropDownListView;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
10-23 11:51:33.610 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000a
10-23 11:51:33.610 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.View.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.setPressedItem
10-23 11:51:33.610 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 21702: Landroid/view/View;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
10-23 11:51:33.610 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x004a
10-23 11:51:33.650 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-23 11:51:35.111 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/AbsListView: onDetachedFromWindow
10-23 11:51:35.322 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
10-23 11:51:45.341 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 849K, 23% free 6682K/8588K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
10-23 11:51:45.341 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 11.460MB for 4096016-byte allocation
10-23 11:51:45.361 7755-7764/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 16% free 10682K/12592K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
10-23 11:51:45.491 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 110K, 16% free 10613K/12592K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
10-23 11:51:45.501 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 15.299MB for 4096016-byte allocation
10-23 11:51:45.522 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 14613K/16596K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
10-23 11:51:46.502 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7755 SIG: 9

This part is red in color:
10-23 11:51:35.322 7755-7755/ambika.amruta.pani.bctdonate100 E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Comment: Please update your question with error you see in error log so that we can take a look further

Comment: Iam a newbee, Don't know how to get error log

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this#23353174

Comment: You really need to print some errors within that `catch (IOException exception)` so you know what's wrong

Comment: Are you sure you copied that from the website? It uses an AsyncTask, where you seems you have modified that...

Comment: I did not understand the AsyncTask. I have taken the part where it is collecting the data and storing on Google Spreadsheet. Also, there are no errors while Build generation or APK generation. The error "app stopped working" is visible once I click submit button of the app. Can you suggest what would be the command set to trap the error on the device and where to find the captured data.

Comment: If your app stops working you are not catching the right exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error in below code check three arguments has given properly DonName,Donphnum,Donemail

```
postBody = NAME_KEY+"=" + URLEncoder.encode(DonName,"UTF-8") +
                "&" + PHONE_KEY + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Donphnum,"UTF-8") +
                "&" + EMAIL_KEY + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Donemail,"UTF-8");
```

and put all code in asynctask like this

```
//AsyncTask to send data as a http POST request
    private class PostDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... contactData) {
            Boolean result = true;
            String url = contactData[0];
            String email = contactData[1];
            String subject = contactData[2];
            String message = contactData[3];
            String postBody="";

            try {
                //all values must be URL encoded to make sure that special characters like & | ",etc.
                //do not cause problems
                postBody = EMAIL_KEY+"=" + URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8") + 
                            "&" + SUBJECT_KEY + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(subject,"UTF-8") + 
                            "&" + MESSAGE_KEY + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(message,"UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                result=false;
            }

            /*
            //If you want to use HttpRequest class from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2253280/1261816
            try {
            HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
            httpRequest.sendPost(url, postBody);
        }catch (Exception exception){
            result = false;
        }
            */

            try{
                //Create OkHttpClient for sending request
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                //Create the request body with the help of Media Type
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(FORM_DATA_TYPE, postBody);
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
                //Send the request
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            }catch (IOException exception){
                result=false;
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
            //Print Success or failure message accordingly
            Toast.makeText(context,result?"Message successfully sent!":"There was some error in sending message. Please try again after some time.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

and when you click on button

```
PostDataTask postDataTask = new PostDataTask();

                //execute asynctask
                postDataTask.execute(URL,emailEditText.getText().toString(),
                        subjectEditText.getText().toString(),
                        messageEditText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: added the code as suggested, the error now is "Error:(332, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

Comment: Worked like a charm.. The rest of the activities on clicking button are OK. But the sheet is not updated.

Comment: Remove logs from answer and post log separate from code, for updating spreadsheet check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753329/writing-to-google-drive-spreadsheet

Comment: Posted the trace separately. On the link, I could not understand on how to follow forward. Do I need to put all the code in this?

Comment: The code you are using might be outdated, so you can try with provided code on link https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157335/discussion-between-krutik-and-sriram-nadiminti).