# How to save data to Local google sheets

Tags: java, javascript, android, google-drive-api, google-sheets

Hi I am developing an android app for a robotics competition. In the app we have buttons that add numbers to text boxes. I would like to get the number and save it to a locally stored Google sheet. Or to try to explain it the Google spreadsheet will be downloaded first then the app will put data in it on each separate device and when we are back on the internet it will upload to Google's servers I cannot find any way to do this and I am new and don't know how to save things yet so please explain carefully. So far the link hasn't been helpful. Can you even put data in a local table I could really use more specific examples I have figured out how to make the app save data then read it to a text box but now I want to put that data in google sheets and the api documentation has not been helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add libraries for accessing the google spread sheets. The following link has a brief on it:

[Android - Google Spreadsheet Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838963/android-google-spreadsheet-api)